# Чи можна "сидіти в Інтернеті"

Tags: вживання-слів, значення-слів

Цікавить чи можна "сидіти в Інтернеті"? Досить часто можна почути даний вислів, але чи є він правильний? Ось є приклад із статті "[Як безпечно сидіти в Інтернеті](http://vidpoviday.com/yak-bezpechno-siditi-v-interneti)":

> Зараз я дам вам кілька порад, як можна безпечно сидіти в інтернеті.

Однак, стаття із Інтернету не може бути надійним джерелом. Якщо подивитися значення слова "[сидіти](http://sum.in.ua/s/sydity)" в СУМі, то можна побачити, що там немає потрібного визначення.

Хоча там є таке визначення:

> Перебувати де-небудь; проводити час десь, у когось

Однак, якщо подивитися приклади, то можна побачити, що всі вони про якісь конкретні, реальні місця - дім, окопи, у розвідників тощо (там нема таких приклад, накшталт "сидіти в грі", "сидіти в телефоні" тощо). Тому я не впевнений чи можна сказати "сидіти в Інтернеті". Можливо краще казати "користуватися Інтернетом"?

Чи все ж таки можна написати "сидіти в Інтернеті", наприклад, у творі ЗНО і не переживати, що це буде помилка.

Comment: Інтернет - це глобальна мережа і фізично ти не можеш "сидіти" в ній. Я б сказав "як безпечно використувавати інтернет" або "як безпечно користуватися інтернетом"

Comment: Є ж сидіти на дієті, на наркотиках, тощо. Не обов'язково саме фізично сідати на щось.

Comment: Можна сидіти в буцегарні або відбувати термін в тюрмі, залежить що вам краще звучить. Так само можна активно займатися веб-серфінгом через браузер, замість того щоб  тупо просидіти час Інтернеті.

Answer (score 2):

"Сидіти в інтернеті" - це фразеологізм.

[Фразеологізм](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D0%B7%D0%BC) — семантично пов'язане сполучення слів, яке, на відміну від подібних до нього за формою синтаксичних структур (висловів або речень), не виникає в процесі мовлення відповідно до загальних граматичних і значеннєвих закономірностей поєднання лексем, а відтворюється у вигляді усталеної, неподільної, цілісної конструкції. Ще його називають «Крилатим висловом».

Що означає сидіти за комп'ютером в оглядачі павутини. Хоча навряд потрібне пояснення значення. Швидше тут невідомо було до чого віднести.

Comment: "Грати на нервах" — теж фразеологізм, але той же СУМ таке значення [реєструє](http://sum.in.ua/s/ghraty).

Answer (score 2):

Словники не задають стандарт мови, а відображають її використання. Якщо всі носії використовують вислів "сидіти в інтернеті", а ваш словник такого значення не вказує, то це недопрацювання словника.

Comment: Так відповіді на питання немає. Цей questions поганий. Тепер я хоч розумію, чому він такий в'ялий і вимирає. Мені набридло витрачати тут час. Помирайте далі.

Comment: @AndriyIvanchenko, може, Ви маєте ідеї, як змінити ситуацію на краще?

Answer (score 1):

"Сидіти в інтернеті" - загальноприйнятий вираз. Не завжди слова використовуються у прямому розумінні. Тут фразеологізм, який з'явився нещодавно (з появою інтернету), ось ви й плутаєтесь

Answer (score 1):

Приклади вживання в сучасній літературі:

- «Мабуть, таким способом хоче випросити собі дозвіл довго сидіти в інтернеті» (Ірина Потаніна, «Білявки мого чоловіка», 2006, Київ, «Гамазин»).
- «Вони робили свої справи: хто сидів в Інтернеті, хто пив чай або каву, хто гортав довідники», «Ти наспівував якусь пісню, коли сидів в Інтернеті, схоже, що ти співав італійською» (Євген Положій, «Дядечко на ім’я Бог», 2008, Харків, «Фоліо»).
- «В такі миті він гарячково дзвонив комусь по телефону, через десятих знайомих надсилав запити до довідкових служб, годинами сидів в інтернеті і шукав, шукав!» (Наталя Тисовська, «Останній шаман», 2008).
- «Знаю чоловіків, які годинами сидять в інтернеті, торгуючи акціями» (Джон Елдредж (переклад — Олена Фешовець), «Дике серце. Таємниця чоловічої душі», 2009, Львів, «Свічадо»).
- «Годинами сидить в інтернеті», «— Сидить в інтернеті», «Сиджу в інтернеті» (Ліна Костенко, «Записки українського самашедшого», 2010).
- «Сиджу в Інтернеті, ходжу по бібліотеках, музеях, іноді йду на Дніпро» (Ярослав Трінчук, «Анахорет», 2012).
- «Він йде звідси, хоч міг би ще годину-дві читати або дивитися телевізор, сидіти в Інтернеті чи слухати свою улюблену музику», «Олег сидів в Інтернеті, поруч з ноутбуком стояла брудна тарілка із засохлою калюжкою кетчупу» (Галина Вдовиченко, «Купальниця», 2012, Харків, «Клуб Сімейного Дозвілля»).
- «От усі тепер говорять про те, що молодь не цікавиться літературою, мистецтвом, знай собі їсть гамбургери або чіпси, п'є пиво чи кока-колу та цілими днями й ночами сидить в Інтернеті» (Лариса Денисенко, «Нова стара баба (збірка)», 2012, Харків, «Клуб Сімейного Дозвілля»).
- «Перед цим Віка якийсь час сиділа в Інтернеті й щось писала» (Руслан Горовий, «Казки на ніч», 2015 (видано 2016), Харків, «Клуб Сімейного Дозвілля»).
- «Ви проводите час зі своїми дітьми, поки дивитесь телевізор, сидите в Інтернеті на планшеті або думаєте про проблеми на роботі» (Ден Вальдшмідт (переклад — Карина Меньшикова), «Вийди за межі. Забудь про успіх — стань видатним!», 2015, Харків, «Клуб Сімейного Дозвілля»).
- «У мене і на роботі, й удома досить часу, щоб сидіти в інтернеті, і я не тупа, повірте» (Олексій Волков, «Вовчий місяць», 2016, Київ, «Нора-Друк»).
- «Уляна годинами сиділа в інтернеті, розшукуючи крихти інформації, але окрім стандартних повідомлень новинних агенцій нічого не знаходилося» (Брати Капранови, «Забудь-річка», 2016, Київ, «Нора-Друк»).
- «По-перше, звідки що взялося? — адже ще навесні 2013-го ми всі вважали, що українці не вийдуть на Майдан, бо розчаровані, бо їх надурять, бо революції роблять романтики, а використовують негідники, бо всі тільки сидять в Інтернеті…» (Брати Капранови, «Майдан. Таємні файли», 2017, Київ, «Зелений пес»).
- «І щоб менше сиділа в інтернеті, інстаграмі та фейсбуці» (Ольга Купріян, «Щоденник Лоли», 2018, Київ, «Книголав»).
- «Погано вчимося, погано вдягаємося, забагато сидимо в Інтернеті» (Максим Кідрук, «Доки світло не згасне назавжди», 2019, Харків, «Клуб Сімейного Дозвілля»).
- «В які вона ще спить, працює — не весь час сидить в інтернеті чи біля телевізора» (Оксана Мороз, «Боротьба за правду. Як мій дядько переміг брехню», 2020, Київ, «Yakaboo Publishing»).

Ці 16 творів 15 авторів — це, звісно, не надто багато, щоб стверджувати, що фразеологізм дійсно сформувався (NB: це всі літературні трапляння, що я [знайшов у ГРАК-14](https://parasol.vmguest.uni-jena.de/grac_crystal/#concordance?corpname=grac14&tab=advanced&queryselector=cql&default_attr=lemma&cql=%22(?i)%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B4%D1%96%D1%82%D0%B8%22%22(?i)%D0%B2%7C%D1%83%22%22(?i)%D1%96%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82%22&showresults=1).) Але, з іншого боку, СУМ-11 вийшов у 1970-х роках, тому не можна сподіватися побачити в ньому згадки про інтернет.